# Set onClick event in adapter's getView method

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a button on the fist activity(listView) which takes you to the second activity (where an image will be added relating to that clicked item). How do I set the onClick event in the adapter's getView method?

Adapter

```
class ChallengeListAdapter:  BaseAdapter {

    private var challengeDatabase: ChallengeDatabase? = null

    private var context: Context? = null

    constructor(context: Context) {

        challengeDatabase = ChallengeDatabase()

        this.context = context
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        val challenge: Challenge = challengeDatabase?.challengesList?.get(position)
            ?: Challenge(
                "No Name", "No Description")


        var challengeView: View

        var layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = context?.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE
        ) as LayoutInflater


        challengeView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.challenge_row, null)

        challengeView.lblChallengeName.setText(challenge.name)
        challengeView.lblChallengeDesc.setText(challenge.desc)


        return challengeView
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return challengeDatabase?.challengesList?.get(position) ?: Challenge(
            "No Name", "No Des")
    }
    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return challengeDatabase?.challengesList?.size ?: 0
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

```
challengeView.setOnClickListener {
val solutionButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.solution_button)

val Intent = Intent(context, SolutionActivity::class.java)
            Intent.putExtra()
            startActivity(context!!, Intent, null)

        return challengeView
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your getView method

```
 challengeView.setOnClickListener{
    //add your code to load activity
    }
```

Now add your getView method will look like

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        val challenge: Challenge = challengeDatabase?.challengesList?.get(position)
            ?: Challenge(
                "No Name", "No Description")


        var challengeView: View

        var layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = context?.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE
        ) as LayoutInflater


        challengeView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.challenge_row, null)

        challengeView.lblChallengeName.setText(challenge.name)
        challengeView.lblChallengeDesc.setText(challenge.desc)
        challengeView.setOnClickListener{
         val element = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position) 
         val intent = Intent(this, SolutionActivity::class.java)
         intent.putExtra("key", element)
         parent.context.startActivity(intent)
         }

        return challengeView
    }
```

Make sure your **Challange** class implementes **Serializable**

Comment: @FurquanKhan I have just added the code that I was working on to the post. If you could help fix it, that would be great.

Comment: @SKdev I have updated the answer this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As Furqan said, you set the click listener to the item's view.. in this case set it to `challengeView`.

To open the activity from it you need to put the desired info inside a Bundle and create an Intent to open the activity with it. You can start the activity from the view's context or propagate that event up to the adapter's owner until you reach the activity and start it from there (usually better if you are seeking for division of responsibilities).

Some tips to write it in a more idiomatic way:

- the context is not necessary in the constructor. It's a bad habit to pass the context along. You can inflate the view like that:

```
LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    .inflate(R.layout.challenge_row, null)
```

- you can make `challengeView` immutable and even inline it like this:

```
...
return LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    .inflate(R.layout.challenge_row, null)
    ?.apply {
         lblChallengeName.text = challenge.name
         lblChallengeDesc.text = challenge.desc
         setOnClickListener {
              //add your code to load activity
         }
    }
```

- `challangeDatabase` can be a `val` and not null

```
private val challengeDatabase = ChallengeDatabase()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the parameters for Adapter setOnClickListener

```
challengeView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id -> 
    val element = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position) // The item that was clicked
    val intent = Intent(this, SolutionActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("key", element)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```